# Are the LMDB files cross-platform compatible?

Tags: blockchain, lmdb, raspberry-pi

I would like to know if the LMDB files are cross-platform compatible, more specifically between **macOS** and **Linux**. I am trying to import a raw blockchain (that I exported yesterday on macOS) onto a Raspberry Pi 3. However, judging from the current commit rate, it's going to take roughly 19 more days. That isn't feasible. I was thinking, if the LMDB files are compatible, I will just temporarily stop my macOS node, copy over the entire `.bitmonero` directory, and fire them backup up on both platforms. Would that work?

**Note:** The `.bitmonero` directory on the Raspberry Pi 3 is currently on an external USB-attached 5400 rpm drive (exFAT file system).

**Update:**
I copied my `.bitmonero` directory from macOS to Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu MATE 16.04). Started `monerod --detach`, seemed to recognize it, so far so good. After about 1h20m, I am still at block 1175453 and daemon is not catching up:

```
$ monerod status
Creating the logger system
Height: 1175453/1176194 (99.9%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 25.08 MH/s, v3, up to date, 5+0 connections
```

I switched to `--log-level 1`, and am seeing some error messages:

```
2016-Nov-09 22:42:18.803852 [P2P6]ERROR /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.h:94 Unkonown command:1007
2016-Nov-09 22:42:18.804381 [P2P6]ERROR /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/p2p/net_node.h:150 Unkonown command:1007
```

At `--log-level 2` I see an endless series of these errors:

```
2016-Nov-09 22:56:50.576666 Attempting to get output pubkey by global index, but key does not exist
2016-Nov-09 22:56:50.642883 EXCEPTION: Attempting to get output pubkey by global index, but key does not exist
```

Not sure how to debug this further …

Comment: Did you ever find out what these error messages are caused by? The command 1007 error appears to be related to node running fluffy blocks, but is the `key does not exist` error related? http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/upon-running-monerod-i-get-two-errors-cryptonote-protocol-handler-h94-unkonow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of v0.10.0, yes the LMDB files are cross-compatible between 32 and 64bit architectures. They have always been cross-compatible between OSs. They are still byte-order dependent but almost everyone uses little-endian CPUs these days so it's not much of an issue.