# Upon running monerod, I get two errors "cryptonote_protocol_handler.h:94 Unkonown command:1007" and "net_node.h:150 Unkonown command:1007"

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, error-log, compact-blocks

[image]

I have never seen these errors. Is it safe to use cli-wallet to transfer funds? Should I be concerned? Using Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.0.0-release) and macOS Sierra 10.12 (16A323).

Comment: Please add some more information, e.g., which version are you on (you can check this by typing `version` into the daemon) and which OS are you using?

Comment: Added versions to original post

Comment: Same problem here... Same version too.

Answer (score 8):

Someone is running a node that supports fluffy blocks and running on mainnet. In handshake, it's sending a request to find out if you support fluffy blocks, but current release nodes don't know about that command.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1263

Comment: I didn't know that Monero was so close to have thin blocks implemented, I just learned about it and your work today. Thank you for making that happen!

Comment: I'm a big fan of the Monero project, and the community as well, so I wanted to contribute in whatever way I could. The developers were extremely helpful, and I would encourage anyone on the fence to just dive in and start contributing. Every little bit helps.

Comment: So what to do if I have this error?

Comment: Nothing. It is not harmful to you.

Comment: revler1082, I'd add this to your answer too, since you didn't exactly reply to the "what do I do" side of the question.