# Why does `monerod` on Raspberry Pi 3 with a copied LMDB not catch up with new blocks?

Tags: monerod, synchronization, lmdb, raspberry-pi

I have both a macOS system and a Raspberry Pi 3 on the same home network. Both are having Monero release 0.10.1.0 installed. I stopped the daemon on macOS, and then copied the entire `.bitmonero` directory from macOS to the Raspberry Pi 3 (running Ubuntu MATE 16.04), because the LMDB blockchain database should be compatible according to [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2607/280). The copy was made at block height 1202945. Unfortunately, I can't get the `monerod` on the Raspberry Pi to synchronize. Event though it regularly prints something in the log, it seems stuck and currently is 75 blocks behind already:

```
2016-Dec-17 02:12:23.986976 [P2P9][167.114.49.139:18080 OUT]Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1202945 -> 1203019 [Your node is 74 blocks (0 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Dec-17 02:12:24.661208 [P2P0][45.32.187.175:18080 OUT]Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1202945 -> 1203020 [Your node is 75 blocks (0 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Dec-17 02:12:25.103400 [P2P8][37.10.71.83:18080 OUT]Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1202945 -> 1203020 [Your node is 75 blocks (0 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Dec-17 02:12:25.375142 [P2P0][85.194.238.130:18080 OUT]Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1202945 -> 1203020 [Your node is 75 blocks (0 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
```

When I do a `monerod status` it shows this:

```
Creating the logger system
Height: 1202945/1203020 (99.9%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 37.98 MH/s, v3 (next fork in 24.4 days), up to date, 6+0 connections
```

How can I resolve this?

### Update

Started `monerod` with `--add-exclusive-node 192.168.0.115`, my internal node's IP address, to rule out any external connectivity issues.

```
2017-Jan-08 21:48:22.763516 [P2P9][192.168.0.115:18080 OUT]Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1202945 -> 1219550 [Your node is 16605 blocks (23 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
```

After I did `set_log 1`, I got to see 19 of the following errors in `bitmonero.log`, and after that nothing:

```
2017-Jan-08 21:52:46.665384 Attempting to get output pubkey by global index (amount 30000000000000, index 46428, count 46423), but key does not exist
2017-Jan-08 21:52:46.698247 EXCEPTION: Attempting to get output pubkey by global index (amount 30000000000000, index 46428, count 46423), but key does not exist
2017-Jan-08 21:52:48.283107 Attempting to get output pubkey by global index (amount 20000000000000, index 75368, count 75366), but key does not exist
2017-Jan-08 21:52:48.322563 EXCEPTION: Attempting to get output pubkey by global index (amount 20000000000000, index 75368, count 75366), but key does not exist
2017-Jan-08 21:52:49.951894 Attempting to get output pubkey by global index (amount 10000000000000, index 914594, count 914594), but key does not exist
2017-Jan-08 21:52:49.952457 EXCEPTION: Attempting to get output pubkey by global index (amount 10000000000000, index 914594, count 914594), but key does not exist
```

When I do a `status` after this, I got an error because the `monerod` process seemed to be no longer there (pressumably crashed).

Comment: I have run into the same issue when attempting to copy the blockchain from my local windows PC to a flash drive and then pointing the daemon to the blockchain on the flash drive using "--data-dir=X:\your\blockchain" when starting the daemon in the GUI. Any help resolving this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Same issue here. It seems to be stuck at 98.5% on block 1200001. I'm on the same version on Winx64.  It updated the LMDB data fine and then synchronized about two months worth of blockchain data via the net. Now it is just stuck with a ton of messages like this: `Attempting to get output pubkey by global index (amount 7000000000, index 231993, count 201901), but key does not exist` using `log-level=1`

Comment: I just restarted my `monerod` on the Pi, but no success. It printed i times the above message (`SYNCHRONIZATION started`) and then nothing anymore. Still stuck at the blockheight of copy time.

Comment: It's stuck at block 1202945, correct? What messages does it show when you run it with `monerod --log-level=1`? Or if monerod is currently running, `set_log 1`?

Comment: Posted an update in question itself.

Comment: No idea. I've moved LMDB files between my Linux PC and raspberry Pi without any trouble, as well as between Windows and Linux.

Comment: I'm going to try running Monero node on that Suse 64 bit build for RaspPi, I'll let you know how it goes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the ARMv7-specific source code, which was triggered when using newer versions of GCC to compile the code.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1991

It has recently been fixed.

Comment: A bit late, but I was able to keep a copied LMDB (from macOS to Raspberry Pi 3) synchronized with the network using the v0.11.1.0 release.