# Monerod synchronization so slow it can't catch up to Blockchain on Raspberry Pi 4 + SSD

Tags: monerod, synchronization, raspberry-pi

I want to set up a Monero full node on my new Raspberry Pi 4.

First, I've downloaded the full blockchain by running `monerod` on my laptop on an external SSD, because I noticed doing so on the Raspberry Pi itself is much slower.

Then, I plugged the SSD in my Raspberry Pi and ran `monerod` from there. Naturally, the node would be a few blocks behind, so it would have to sync.

At first I thought it didn't sync at all, since it would reach the point where it said `SYNCHRONIZATION started` and not show any of the progress, as I would expect. However, by waiting much longer, I saw that it was actually syncing. But it was syncing extremely slowly. Moreover, by waiting even longer, I started to see the progress going backwards! In other words, it is syncing so slowly that it couldn't even keep up with the 1 block/2minutes Monero block rate!

Here is the output:

```
New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.3.0-release)
Forking to background...
Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.3.0-release) Daemonised
Initializing cryptonote protocol...
Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
Initializing core...
Loading blockchain from folder ./lmdb ...
Loading checkpoints
Core initialized OK
Initializing p2p server...
p2p server initialized OK
Initializing core RPC server...
Binding on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4):18081
core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
Starting core RPC server...
core RPC server started ok
Starting p2p net loop...

**********************************************************************
The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. This may take a long time to complete.

You can set the level of process detailization through "set_log <level|categories>" command,
where <level> is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING).

Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
Use "help <command>" to see a command's documentation.
**********************************************************************
[43.245.222.219:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543080 -> 2543156 [Your node is 76 blocks (2.5 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
Synced 2543100/2543171 (99%, 71 left, 21% of total synced, estimated 1.9 hours left)
[68.12.134.6:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543100 -> 2543174 [Your node is 74 blocks (2.5 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
Synced 2543120/2543186 (99%, 66 left, 37% of total synced, estimated 1.7 hours left)
[94.198.42.120:56226 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543187 [Your node is 67 blocks (2.2 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[45.79.114.71:33714 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543187 [Your node is 67 blocks (2.2 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[73.166.84.222:19435 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543187 [Your node is 67 blocks (2.2 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[73.171.79.153:58606 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543188 [Your node is 68 blocks (2.3 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[73.14.231.241:53864 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543190 [Your node is 70 blocks (2.3 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[66.42.48.120:57517 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543190 [Your node is 70 blocks (2.3 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[23.88.124.126:49968 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543190 [Your node is 70 blocks (2.3 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[213.91.128.133:37166 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543190 [Your node is 70 blocks (2.3 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[188.187.188.52:62335 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543193 [Your node is 73 blocks (2.4 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[180.176.96.6:40534 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543197 [Your node is 77 blocks (2.6 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[51.81.244.164:38400 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543199 [Your node is 79 blocks (2.6 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[95.216.139.44:48582 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543203 [Your node is 83 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[47.108.203.74:55768 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543204 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[83.221.206.99:59268 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543204 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[86.152.232.180:55846 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543204 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[208.107.235.121:39310 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543204 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[46.124.184.86:52170 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543204 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[142.93.48.86:56630 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543205 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[165.232.181.42:48014 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543205 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[24.207.209.37:36986 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543205 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[104.2.253.10:48780 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543205 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[52.199.102.11:52696 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543205 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[165.22.2.129:45178 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543205 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[74.40.163.194:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543206 [Your node is 86 blocks (2.9 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[144.126.141.191:39974 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543212 [Your node is 92 blocks (3.1 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[185.192.71.27:34180 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543216 [Your node is 96 blocks (3.2 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[79.225.185.145:52848 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543217 [Your node is 97 blocks (3.2 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[188.192.63.99:54274 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543120 -> 2543218 [Your node is 98 blocks (3.3 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
Synced 2543140/2543219 (99%, 79 left, 43% of total synced, estimated 2.6 hours left)
[63.229.31.6:53286 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543220 [Your node is 80 blocks (2.7 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[144.217.81.221:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543221 [Your node is 81 blocks (2.7 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[24.107.195.111:65144 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543222 [Your node is 82 blocks (2.7 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[75.133.137.150:52400 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543222 [Your node is 82 blocks (2.7 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[65.108.81.124:37458 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543223 [Your node is 83 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[62.181.62.177:36654 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543223 [Your node is 83 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[86.98.33.33:64918 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543222 [Your node is 82 blocks (2.7 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[185.220.101.54:11834 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543223 [Your node is 83 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[95.216.199.217:49882 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543224 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[165.232.190.164:42214 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543224 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[78.46.192.204:53188 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543224 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[134.209.31.237:39728 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543224 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[144.34.176.187:63184 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543224 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[100.36.49.207:18693 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543224 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[95.216.199.217:50408 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543224 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[85.201.248.87:51665 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543225 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[46.105.122.112:48386 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543225 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[66.17.104.161:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543226 [Your node is 86 blocks (2.9 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[23.25.183.30:51963 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543230 [Your node is 90 blocks (3.0 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[104.254.93.163:45048 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543140 -> 2543231 [Your node is 91 blocks (3.0 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
Synced 2543156/2543238 (99%, 82 left, 48% of total synced, estimated 2.7 hours left)
[143.244.163.97:60890 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543156 -> 2543239 [Your node is 83 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[168.119.69.50:33854 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543156 -> 2543239 [Your node is 83 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[222.90.75.74:49952 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543156 -> 2543240 [Your node is 84 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
[159.69.196.212:58210 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2543156 -> 2543241 [Your node is 85 blocks (2.8 hours) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
Synced 2543157/2543242 (99%, 85 left, 47% of total synced, estimated 3.0 hours left)
```

Note how the node is even further behind after about 4 hours of syncing than it was at the start.

I saw that a very similar question has already been asked
[here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/why-does-monerod-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-a-copied-lmdb-not-catch-up-with-new-bl), however, the accepted answer to that question mentions a bug which was supposedly fixed when that answer was posted (in 2017).

I don't believe that my network speed is to blame, nor do I think it's the disk speed. What could be causing this? How could I speed it up?

Comment: incase not urgent: start the daemon in terminal (non-daemonized) on a fresh datadir and let it be for few days. Meanwhile check via `htop` if your rpi is running low on resources cpu/ram, or even power (which causes cpu throttling).

Comment: @qrtLs That's what I did originally, but the syncing was too slow. I had already left it a week and it only synced about 20% of the blockchain's full size, getting slower and slower as it progressed. That's why I synced most of it on my laptop.
Using `htop` I'm not seeing it using a large amount of memory (442M/3.7G), but `monerod` is indeed using almost all of the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

The disk I/O was slow. My disk had an `exfat` filesystem. I changed it to a `ext4` filesystem, and synchronization ran fine then.